# Want to run the application on remote machine, which is part of different network

Tags: c#

In my application , I have to kick off the job on remote machine
I used PeExec Tool to perform the Task. Its working fine and able to kick off the job remotely.

About PsExec Tool refer :http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

Here both the machine connected through network.

Command : `PsExec.exe \\MachineIP -u qa -p qa -h -i "c:\AutomationTool.exe"`

But now i want to kick off the job in the machine, Which is not part of the network.
I used same PsExec but it's throwing error as

> PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely\r\nCopyright (C) 2001-2010
>   Mark Russinovich\r\nSysinternals - www.sysinternals.com\r\n\r\nThe
>   handle is invalid.\r\nConnecting to 10.90.206.177...\r\r\rCouldn't
>   access 10.90.206.177:\r\nConnecting to 10.90.206.177..

Please help me to understand whether  PsExec Tool will support to execute job in different networks,
If so pleae let me know the Configuration settings to establish networks connection.

Comment: `PsExec.exe \\localhost ...` sounds promising

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible, as PSEXEC is a Network tool and allows you to access remote machines across a network.

Can you do any of the following :-

> 1.) Do you have permission to connect the IP address?
>
> 2.) If you go to start\run in windows, and type this address, does it allow you to browse the c: Drive?
>
> 3.) If you ping that Address do you receive any packets?

I highly doubt you can achieve any of the above steps.

You may need to look at a different method entirely.

Hope This Helps.